# Using Tenser’s Floating Disc as propulsion

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

For D&D 5e, TFD states that when I move more than 20’ away, TFD

> ...follows you so that it remains within 20’...

I cast TFD and place one end of a 25’ long beam on it. On the other end is a seat and wheels.  Will TFD move toward me in perpetuity at my normal movement until I dismount from the far end of the beam?

Comment: I've undeleted this because duplicates are good! They still earn you reputation too. Duplicates make it easier to find the answers by providing multiple phrasings that can be successfully searched for, so they get you your answer and help improve the site for everyone.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up on duplicates and for linking it to the already answered question.